# Why does typescript complain about a computed property name?

Tags: typescript

Using typescript Version 3.7.5. I have these two simple types and I would expect that either both of them compile or neither do. However, typescript only complains about the second one. Why is the second type invalid, but the first isn't?

```
// this works
type foo = {
  [key in 'xxx']: number
}

// this does not
type bar = {
  xxx: number
  [key in 'xxx']: number
}
```

Here are the compiler messages:

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.ts(2361)
```

See the code in action [in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.7.5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=2#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQO4HsBOBrWAocBPADgKagBmSSoAvKAN6aigDaaBOo0AdqAOQAefXAXQBcodgFcAtgCMCKTAF9MmEBBjwAJkgLx2ScNnxEpAQxSUadUHx4jx02ZaYs2nXv2GjJMuYqA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition is a *mapped type* ([doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)), which binds `key`, so you can use it in the right-hand side, e.g.:

```
type foo = {
  [key in 'xxx']: key
}
```

You cannot add properties to mapped types though. For example, for

```
type foo = {
  [key in 'xxx']: key
   xxx: number
}
```

TypeScript will show an error about an expected `}` at the position of `xxx`.

On the other hand,

```
type bar = {
  xxx: number
  [key in 'xxx']: number
}
```

is a regular type literal, in which `[key in 'xxx']: number` is a computed property, for which the restrictions mentioned in the first two error messages hold.

The third error message comes from TypeScript interpreting `in` as the regular expression-level `in`. You can see the same error here:

```
const error = key in 'xxx'
```

(and if you hover over `key` in your second example, you'll also see a `Cannot find name 'key'.` error)

Comment: Ah...makes sense. Thanks. And to fix this I should be using an intersection type. This is now working. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.7.5&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQO4HsBOBrWAocBPADgKagBmSSoAvKAN6aigDaaBOo0AdqAOQAefXAXQBcodgFcAtgCMCKTAF9MmEBBjxk6eOyQIAhNnxEpAQxSUadRs1YdufHoJHjpshaABkNUPaeSZZxSA